# JavaScript parsing with Java

Tags: java, javascript, parsing

I am looking for some help with parsing JavaScript variables and arrays from a .js file from the web.
Something like Jsoup except it parses JavaScript rather than HTML. Any suggestions on how I could manage something like this?

Comment: How about posting what you want and what you have. Another tip, http://sscce.org/ :)

Comment: [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/about) is not a discussion board nor a search engine, so that we do not discuss or recomend software solutions here.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Java 1.6 JavaScript parser Rhino is a part of JDK.

Take a look on the official tutorial from Oracle: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure if Rhino was what I wanted.